# Do Gravity Forms | The Best WordPress Form Plugin | Form Builder supports preview before submission

Tags: wordpress, gravityforms

Do Gravity forms provide a preview feature before submitting the form?
Did anyone use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the Gravity Forms Preview Submission add-on:

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-preview-submission/

To use it:

1. Add an HTML field to your form.
2. Populate any merge tags you'd like into the HTML field:
   [image: HTML field settings w/ merge tags]